# fetch multiple rows from associated model using findOne() method in sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two models/tables, **1**. purchase and **2**. purchaseItem, these two tables are associated using `purchase.hasOne(purchaseItem)`. And I want fetch only one purchase but all it's corresponding/realated items.

I tried this...

```js
Purchase.findOne({
        where: { id: purchaseId },
        include: {
            model: PurchaseItem,
        },
    })
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp)))
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

But it fetches only one item instead of all related items.
And If I use `findAll()` method, it repeats the same purchase multiple times(according items count).
I want to fetch only one purchase and all its related items.

Comment: `purchase.hasOne(purchaseItem)` this only make one-to-one relation, I think you should use `purchase.hasMany(purchaseItem)`

Comment: @DhavalDarji Yes, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome, Give comment vote up, And Keep learning Keep growing.